# Unity persistentDataPath issue on update

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've got a problem with finding savefiles on user devices. Usually it all works like this:

```
 if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + fileName)) {
            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + fileName);
```

and that's just fine, except for when Android players have the game installed on a SD card and an update from the Google Play Store makes the app being installed in the internal storage. This causes the Application.persistentDataPath to be the internal path, but the savefile is still at the external path and so the savegame can't be found and players have the problem that they seemingly lost their progress.

Is there a better nice way to handle this than storing the savefile into the PlayerPrefs? I really like being able to ask players for their savefile in case something is wrong with it, so they can just send it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Store the file path in PlayerPrefs

Rather than storing the whole file in PlayerPrefs, just store the *path* you saved it at instead. Something like this:

```
public static string GetSaveFilePath(string fileName){
    
    // Got a path already?
    string path = PlayerPrefs.GetString(fileName+"-location");

    if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ){
        
        // Nope - create a path now:
        path = Application.persistentDataPath + fileName;

        // Save the path:
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(fileName+"-location", path);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    return path;
}
```

Then rather than using `Application.persistentDataPath`, use `GetSaveFilePath` instead:

```
string path = GetSaveFilePath("save.dat");

if (File.Exists(path)) {
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, the more common approach is to add a button within your app to upload any information you find useful for debugging etc, then store anything you need in PlayerPrefs so it can "just work" (i.e. it becomes unnecessary to have it as a separate file).

Comment: That looks good I'd say. I'm gonna test, if I it works on Android and iOS. :)